# SQL Server : trigger on after insert into multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, insert

In a SQL Server database that I am setting up, there are a few 1 to many tables that I would like to create the "many" table records after the parent record is inserted, inserting only the auto generated ID value and another value from the parent record.

For instance:

- Table 1 (Parent): Auto_ID, Name, createby, createdatetime
- Table 2 (Child): Auto_ID, Parent_Auto_ID, Col1, Col2, createby, createdatetime
- Table 3 (Child): Parent_Auto_ID, Col1, createby, createdatetime

I already have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ipamuserInsert] 
ON [dbbo].[ipamuser]
FOR INSERT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[ipamuserdefault]
        (ipamuserID, homepage, createby, createdatetime)
    VALUES
        SELECT 
            ipamuserID,
            NULL,
            createby,
            GETDATE()
        FROM 
            inserted

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[ipamextlink]
        (ipamuserID, link, createby, GETDATE())
    VALUES
        SELECT
            ipamuserID, null, createby, GETDATE()
        FROM
            inserted
    GO
```

Is this the right syntax, or do I need to declare a separate temp variable and store the ipamuserID and the createby values and use those instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant test this without your table definitions but I think that you are spot on.

Depending on the number of tables involved I would consider making this dynamic.  The number of tables would have to be high to make it worth the effort though.

Editbased on comment:
You can make this dynamic by using system views to find out what tables are related and generate your Sql dynamically based on the metadata.  Here are a couple articles to get you started.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177862.aspx

The basic structure would be to create a cursor loop for each related table and an inner cursor loop for each column in the related table.  You would build the sql statement dynamically in the same format as you have it defined in your question.

Comment: Ok, on average there are 3 child tables to every 1 to many parent tables that I am needing to do this for. I am not sure how I would make this dynamic.

Comment: If you have 3 parent tables with three child tables I would stick with what you proposed.  If have maybe 30+ parent tables you can query system views to find the foreign key constraints to find the tables you need to insert a 'default row' into.